# Toast.makeText and Log not showing for Location Service

Tags: java, android

Currently making a Location Service for an app I'm currently building. I'm trying to print the obtained latitude and longitude through a Log and through a Toast.makeText from a broadcast receiver but nothing is showing when I run. Was hoping if you guys could see any faults.

**LocationService.java**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class LocationService extends Service {

FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
LocationCallback locationCallback;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){

        // Whenever there is a Location Update, this method is where it occurs
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            // Log Result for Longitude and Latitude, call method to receive elsewhere
            Log.d("Location Log", "Latitude is: " + locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude() +
                    "Longitude is: " + locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
            Intent intent = new Intent("ACT_LOC");
            intent.putExtra("Latitude", locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude());
            intent.putExtra("Longitude", locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    };
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    requestLocation();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

// Method to request the Location every 3 seconds
private void requestLocation(){
    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, 
    Looper.myLooper());
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        // If the permission Access Fine Location is not granted
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // Request Location
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
        else{
            // Request Location Permission
            startService();
        }
    }
    else{
        // Start Location Service
        startService();
    }
}

// Start the service with a new intent for the MainActivity and Location Services
// Register Broadcast Receiver with intent action from LocationService.java
void startService(){
    LocationBroadcastReceiver receiver = new LocationBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("ACT_LOC");
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationServices.class);
    startService(intent);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch(requestCode){
        case 1:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                startService();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Give me permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
}

public class LocationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // check if action is required or not
        if(intent.getAction().equals("ACT_LOC")){
            double lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("Latitude", 0f);
            double lng = intent.getDoubleExtra("Longitude", 0f);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Latitude is: " + lat + ", Longitude is: " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.anongeolocation">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".LocationService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be that you just are not receiving location updates? GPS won't work indoors and "network based" location might require a SIM card.

Answer (score -1):

If log or toast doesnt run it could only have one reason.the compiler doesnt get into their methods somehow.i suggest you log everywhere compiler can  go from on create of main activity and follow logs one by one to find out where exactly compiler is!